# Is it always safe to click first in the lower lefthand corner of a Minesweeper puzzle?

Tags: strategy, minesweeper

I always start a Minesweeper puzzle in Windows by clicking the cell in the lower left corner. Even though I have never seen a bomb there, how sound is this strategy? Is it possible that some time in the future there will be a bomb there? Or is it possible to click anywhere the first time?

Comment: That depends on how the grid is generated.

Comment: @Doorknob I'm referring to the Minesweeper that comes with the Windows operating system. Vista and 7.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about games, and might be better suited for [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @KendallFrey Minesweeper is puzzle-based, and so would be on-topic; Arqade is for videogames!

Comment: Minesweeper *is* a video game, but it is a puzzling one.

Comment: @KendallFrey There are many other questions, not just by Brian, under the [tag:minesweeper] tag. A diamond mod has even asked a question here about [tag:minesweeper].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Many Minesweeper games, including the one that ships with Windows, do not allow the first square you click to be a mine. The lower-left-hand corner is not necessarily safe, but if it's the first square you click, then it will be safe.

Comment: Funny. Sometimes I click elsewhere and it is a bomb.

Comment: Not the very first one you click, that will never be a bomb in the MS version. Go start a game and click the first square. Do that a hundred times and tell me how many times you get a bomb.

Comment: Is it supposed to generate the grid after my first click? because I find that it is also the clearest section.

Comment: I don't know for sure whether it doesn't generate a board until you click or if it generates the grid and just regenerates if you hit a bomb first time, but I really doubt it's generating a grid with a clear area just around where you click. You're probably just experiencing selection bias and/or cognitive dissonance, both are strong and well-documented psychological tendencies.

Comment: The game generates the grid after your first click, yes. It generates it so that the mines are randomly placed anywhere *except* the square you clicked.

Comment: @Kevin I may be getting some puzzles that I restarted mixed up with new ones in my memory.

Comment: Now, note that with that being said, there is an option in the later Windows Minesweeper games that allows you to restart a grid, but if you restart the grid, then the first square you click *may* be a bomb if it was a bomb in the original grid.

Comment: @JoeZ. so you're saying I can literally click anywhere in the puzzle grid, and as long as it's a new game, it won't blow up?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's how the software is programmed.

Comment: The Windows XP version of Minesweeper has a finite number of possible boards. When you click the first spot, it shifts the board around until the square under your mouse isn't a mine.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail, Kevin, do you have a source for that?

Comment: @SQB http://www.minesweeper.info/wiki/Board_Cycles

Comment: @undergroundmonorail That's very interesting. I think a quote of that should be part of the answer, or at least a link to it.

Comment: I remember having a VB.Net program that would tell me where all the mines were. If I purposely clicked on a mine as the first square, the board changed. I would say that's quite verifiable and correct.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail There are a finite number of possible boards anyway. (An upper bound would be 2 to the power of the number of cells)

Answer (score 1):

In at least one version of Windows (I think it was XP that I tried this on), Minesweeper ships with a cheat code that allows seeing whether a square has a mine or not by hovering the mouse on the square without clicking. I once used this to mark every mine on the board before clearing even the first square. I then clicked on one of the known mines. That one mine was moved, but all 98 other mine markings proved still accurate.

The board is generated before you start to play, but the first square you click is forced safe regardless, even if that requires relocating one mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the cells adjacent to the corners have only 5 cells surrounding them, and because the algorithm that means you usually will have bombs next to each other, the minimal amount of cells touching cells creates an area where bombs are less likely to appear. It is also a good strategic move because the cell (if it is not a bomb) will say 1, 2, 3, or 0. 1 gives you a 0% of knowing where to go if you click on it, and 2 or 0 gives you a 100% of knowing where to go if you click on the corner cell. And 3 is a 33.3% chance. Add that up and you get 70.8% of knowing where to go. Cells not on a corner but touching the edge: 54.7%, and cells in the middle: 41.3%. Going in the corner is a good first move in Minesweeper.

Comment: IIRC, at least in the Windows version of Minesweeper, diagonals are counted. So a corner tile can be 0,1,2, or 3.

Comment: @RobertFraser thx. That helps.